# Javascript, how to add multiple buttons and link same Onclick function with different value

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

i have a simple question, but dont know how to do it.  I want to add multiple button in javascript, add ONE onclick and the button have to send the right value;

The right value in this exemple is : Hello", "Bye" or "Hey Gary

My button function dont work and i dont know how to send the right value, help me please

thank you!

```
html
    <div  id="main"> </div>
```

javascript

```
info = ["Hello", "Bye", "Hey Gary"];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<a id='" + info[i] + "'  class='list-group-item'>"+info[i]+"</a>";
document.getElementById(info[i]).innerHTML += "<input class='btn btn-danger pull-right'     class='test77' value='send'>";
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<br><hr></hr>";
}
    createbutton();

function createbutton() {
$(".test77").click(function () {
alert("i want to send information at the left");
});
}
```

Jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/prodeinfo/sep1jzpc/2/

Comment: Could you please update your question and give us an example of what you expect to happen when the button is clicked?  We have no idea what the "right" value is.

Comment: I just update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input should be of `type="button"`, and you have the button's `class` defined twice.

```js
info = ["Hello", "Bye", "Hey Gary"];
for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<a id='" + info[i] + "'  class='list-group-item'><span>" + info[i] + "</span></a>";
  document.getElementById(info[i]).innerHTML += "<input type='button' class='btn btn-danger pull-right test77'  value='send'>";
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<br><hr></hr>";
}
createbutton();

function createbutton() {
  $(".test77").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().find('span').text());
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not much clear about what LEFT is. But probably you are asking for the following.

```
function createbutton() {
    $(".test77").click(function (e) {
       var text = e.target.previousSibling.innerText;
       alert(text);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what are you looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var info = ["Hello", "Bye", "Hey Gary"];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
 document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<a id='" + info[i] + "' class='list-group-item'>"+info[i]+"</a>";
 document.getElementById(info[i]).innerHTML += "<input class='myBtn btn btn-danger pull-right'   class='test77' value='send'>";
 document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<br><hr></hr>";
}

createbutton();
           
function createbutton() {
 $(".myBtn").click(function () {
  var value = $(this).closest("a").text();
  alert(value);
 });
}
 




});
```

```css
.pull-right {
    float: right!important;
}
.btn-danger {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d43f3a;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="main"> </div>
```